# Increasing the smoothness of a wave

Tags: qgis, vector, geometry-generator, qgsexpression

I wrote a Geometry Generator expression to create a sine wave in the canvas (don't ask, just having fun):

```
with_variable(
    'points',
    map(
        'point_middle_left', 
        make_point(x(@map_extent_center)-(@map_extent_width/2), y(@map_extent_center)),
        'point_middle_right',
        make_point(x(@map_extent_center)+(@map_extent_width/2), y(@map_extent_center))
    ),
    wave(
        densify_by_count(
            make_line(
                map_get(@points, 'point_middle_left'), 
                map_get(@points, 'point_middle_right')
            ),
            vertices:=100
        ),
        wavelength:=42,
        amplitude:=23,
        strict:=True
    )
)
```

The resulting sine wave line is not smooth though, you can see very distinguished linear segments of the line:

[image]

How can I increase the node density in the `wave` output (basically the sampling frequency along the line) so that the resulting line is smoother?

I noticed that the documentation for the `wave` function says "Constructs rounded (sine-like) waves along the **boundary** of a geometry." (emphasis mine) so maybe it only considers the start and end point of the line and there is no way. Asking does not hurt though.

I did add a `densify_by_count(...)` around the line before passing it to the `wave` function but that does not change anything.

I do not want to use a `smooth(...)` around the result.

Comment: I love this kind of questions and love the `wavelength` and `amplitude` values ! For me, this is typically the `smooth` function, but you don't want it.